# Homomorphism from matrix to complex set.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone please help me simplify the homomorphism property. If $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$

Let $f$ be a homomorphism.

$f(A) = (az + b)/(cz + d)$, where $A$ is a determinant from the $GL(2,\mathbb C)$ and $\mathbb C$ is the complex set. In addition, the $\det A$ is not equal to zero. And $a$, $b$, $c$,and $d$ are complex elements.

I know the operation is composition.

Attempt: Let $A$, $B$ be matrices in $GL(2,\mathbb C)$. Then 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're probably having a hard time who this because you haven't stated the problem very clearly. Try to be more precise. What is $A$? I doubt it is a determinant, since that is just a number. Do you mean $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with entries $a,b,c,d$? And the alleged homomorphism sends such an $A$ to the indicated rational function?